# Is it possible to get a TFS workitem snapshot for a specific date using TFS query?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I require to get all "Bug" entities from a TFS Team Project, for a specific date, it means that entities atributes should have values they had the date I specify. Kind of all bugs snapshot for a specific day.

Is it posible to do via a TFS query?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can not do this via standart tools provided by TFS portal.
But there is TFS API for you. Look at `WorkItemStore` class. It has many methods including `GetWorkItem(Int32, DateTime)`   `Gets the previous state of a work item that is specified by ID and date`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.aspx

Comment: That is second solution for this situation. I thought I will find a an easy way of getting it. Thanks.